# Put Python Dictionary in List and Call it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am making a game in python and want to store dictionaries with lists, e.g.:

```
swords = [
    wooden_sword = {'name': 'Wooden Sword'}
    stone_sword = {'name': 'Stone Sword'}

]
```

Is this possible and if so can I do things like:

```
print(swords[wooden_sword['name']])
```

Or assign things to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to make your `swords` variable a dictionary. Then you can access the wooden sword like this:

```
swords = {
    'wooden_sword': {'name': 'Wooden Sword'},
    'stone_sword': {'name': 'Stone Sword'}
}

print(swords['wooden_sword']['name'])
```

will print

```
"Wooden Sword"
```

The other option is to filter your list by `'name'` like this

```
swords = [
    {'name': 'Wooden Sword', 'damage': 5},
    {'name': 'Stone Sword', 'damage': 10}
]
name = 'Wooden Sword'
sword = filter(lamda s: s['name'] == name, swords)

print(sword)
```

will print

```
{'name': 'Wooden Sword', 'damage': 5}
```